# Is there a mechanism which can be used to 'advertise' an Area 51 proposal on other sites when relevant to the question?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-promotion

[I've created a proposal for a Salesforce Stack Exchange site on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce?referrer=4-k5FqV679TWbBGLxdLUKg2), primarily because I see a number of Salesforce questions closed on Stack Overflow because they're off-topic — the reason being that relate to the declarative side of development on the platform, as opposed to the coding side. It is this aspect which makes the platform relatively unique, as Salesforce 'development' can be quite involved without any code being used.

I've read the similar questions here, and they're asking about promoting Area 51 sites in general — the difference here is that I believe getting a large number of people to commit to this one won't be a challenge, the Salesforce community is large and very social by nature. It will be a challenge reaching the required number of *commits* from people with a reputation of 200+ elsewhere on the network. It seems to me at this stage that the other sites are still largely technology focused, the upshot being that unless you're interested in something very specific you're not likely to have an account on the network.

There are many Salesforce administrators and consultants who are not developers, but they can answer a lot of the questions which get closed on Stack Overflow — the problem is the chance of them having 200+ rep elsewhere is slim at best. I understand the argument for 100 200+ rep users, but right now it seems to me that the topical range of the other sites in the network will limit the chances of proposals which seek to expand it.

Is there an acceptable way to share a link to the proposal to those people actively responding to, or asking, Salesforce questions on Stack Overflow?

Comment: It was launched a few months later, [at about 2012-07-31](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1/live-agent-ports-ip-addresses) (though that first question was only answered more than two years later).

Comment: Oh I've been moderating it since it went live - my original hunch was correct and it is a very active site on the network!

Answer (score 1):

You could comment on the closed questions saying that they would be a good fit for the site, once it is up and running, and provide a link to the proposal.

Comment: I've actually done this before, and subsequently had the comments removed! I've edited the tag wiki, but I still don't think that's seen by a lot of people.